# XML Processing using Spark Streaming and Kafka - Split single XML file content issue?

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

Since Spark streaming consumes data in micro batches, will there be an issue when consume XML message?

1. If i publish entire XML file as single message to Kafka Topic, when consume using Spark Streaming is there a possibility of splitting the XML file content because of message size.
2. Will Spark streaming consume single XML message in two different DStreams? Is this valid scenario?

Please advise.

Comment: Here is the complete documentation about Kafka and Spark Streaming.http://aseigneurin.github.io/2016/03/03/kafka-spark-avro-consume-messages-with-spark.html

Comment: @Shankar am struggling to solve a similar problem could you please let me know how to construct a xml or how handle xml data in a better way using spark.
Thanks,
Ankush Reddy

Comment: @AnkushReddySugureddy: What is the issue you are facing.. its better you can post a question explaining your specific problem , so i can have a look or someone else can help.